# Drag and Drop from one ListView to another, when dropped the text changes

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

when I try to drag an item from one `listview` to another, the data when dropped says  `System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection` but I have it adding the text `ToString`.
Code:

```
private void CompletedList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}

private void ShipList_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CompletedList.DoDragDrop(ShipList.SelectedItems.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void CompletedList_DragDrop(Object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    CompletedList.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString());
    //ShipList.Items.Remove(e.Data.GetData())
}
```

p.s. I know the `ShipList.Items.Remove` is commented out, I'm still working out how to remove the data from the first box when dropped in the 2nd box

Comment: I think that's because you are printing the actual object type to string by using `.ToString()`. I would recommend reading this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control).

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a simple example. It will not work for list items that have duplicate names or contain commas in their name. It should give you an idea how to start.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            ShipList.Items.Add($"My Item {i}");
    }

    private void CompletedList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void CompletedList_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var listOfItems = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        foreach (string itemText in listOfItems)
        {
            CompletedList.Items.Add(itemText);
            foreach (ListViewItem shipItem in ShipList.Items)
            {
                if (shipItem.Text == itemText)
                {
                    ShipList.Items.Remove(shipItem);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ShipList_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShipList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

        var selectedListNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ShipList.SelectedItems)
            selectedListNames.Add(item.Text);

        CompletedList.DoDragDrop(string.Join(",", selectedListNames), DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```